# C++ method implementations: Can I avoid typing the class name each time?

Tags: c++, namespaces, code-formatting

When I have a C++ class `MyClass` in namespace `mynamespace`, I implement its methods as

```
void mynamespace::MyClass::method() { … }
```

I can wrap that in a namespace to shorten individual definitions to

```
namespace mynamespace {

    void MyClass::method() { ... }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to retype `MyClass::` as well so I can copy everything before the `{` to the header as a prototype more easily whenever the signature changes, without having to remove the `MyClass::` every time?

I thought "a class is also a namespace, maybe I can do"

```
namespace mynamespace::MyClass {

    void method() { ... }

}
```

but that complains that I was re-defining MyClass as a different thing. `using mynamespace::MyClass;` also didn't work (but would be bad anyway because how would I declare a standalone function anywhere below that line in that file if it worked).

Is there a solution to this, or is it simply not possible in C++?

Comment: (99% sure on this) Nope. The class name must appear, otherwise it won't know what class the method belongs to.

Comment: Sure, you could implement your methods at the time you implement the class. But I have a feeling that's not what you want to hear.

Comment: if you use an IDE you can use autocompletion

Comment: Adding to @formerlyknownas_463035818, some IDEs can also "Copy signature" of a function

Comment: Can't auto-complete if there is no declaration for the new method in the header yet, and usually IDEs autocomplete based on the header, so if I edit the implementation, I can't autocomplete the edited implementation's signature into the header, sadly.

Comment: As to implementing my methods in the header: That causes huge problems (exposing implementation details via the header, recommending inlining to the compiler/optimizer, bloating compile times, requiring the header include everything the app uses and "leaking" those dependencies to anyone who includes the header ... so yeah, not really an option in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the qualified class name must appear on any class member defined outside the class definition. (And there can only be one class definition, which is normally in a header file.)

The C++ Standard spells out this rule in [[class.mfct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#class.mfct-4):

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the `​::`​ operator.

and similarly in [[class.static.data]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#class.static.data-2) for static data members.

You might abbreviate this qualification using preprocessor macros, but that would seriously harm legibility and is not a common practice.

Answer (score 3):

There is no idiomatic way to avoid this. Even if you or someone else might come up with a "hack" (macro-based, for example), it would make the code less readable for everyone. The normal and expected way to write C++ is for the member functions to have the preceding `MyClass::` when defined outside the class definition.

I would suggest to look for a tool that can update signatures between header and source file on command.

Or, as the comments suggest, provide the definitions of your functions right with the declaration inside the class definition (i.e. provide inline definitions). But that has its own disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++20 modules, you can implement a class in one file:

```
module myproject.mymodule;

namespace mynamespace {
    export struct my_class {
        auto my_method() -> int {
            return 8;
        }
    };
}
```

Or export a whole namespace fragment:

```
export namespace mynamespace {
    struct my_class {
        auto my_method() -> int {
            return 8;
        }
    };

    auto also_exported() -> void {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, instead of including it, you can import that module:

```
import myproject.mymodule;

auto frob() -> void {
    auto my_instance = mynamespace::my_class{};
}
```

Comment: But we'd still rely on defining the functions already in the class definition, wouldn't we? And if defining them outside, we would again have to repeat the class name, wouldn't we?

Comment: @Aconcagua of course, but with modules you don't have the drawbacks of putting something inside headers, removing most need of separating definitions.

Comment: Well, we could implement the entire class in headers as well. I don't see how that would differ from the module stuff in respect of repeating class scope...

Comment: @Aconcagua yes. You can put your entire codebase into headers. There are reasons we don't do that. Module greatly helps with that since you can put your entire codebase inside interfaces with little drawbacks.

Comment: implementing my methods in the header causes huge problems: exposing implementation details via the header, recommending inlining to the compiler/optimizer, bloating compile times, requiring the header include everything the app uses and "leaking" those dependencies to anyone who includes the header. AFAIK modules in C++ 20 are treated differently by the compiler (basically it "generates an invisible header for you"?) and would therefore not have these drawbacks.

Comment: @uliwitness exactly. GCC and MSVC implement it like that. The "invisible header" only contain needed informations and is stored as a binary format for faster reading. It is called the CMI (compiled module interface)

Comment: Hiding the code base is the keyword I'd refer to. The pre-compiled headers are in binary format. Thus not human readable. Then we need the non-compiled module file to see how a module looks like, don't we? But there's all the code exposed again. If we create a separate module implementation file, we then we again need to repeat the class names, don't we? So modules won't solve the issue of the question, will they? (Don't get me wrong, I'm *not* opposing modules, just that I have my doubts if they're really suitable in this very specific case...).

Comment: @Aconcagua In that case yes. But I don't think all codebases that separates code today do it for hiding code though. There are still cases where you want to seprate definition even with modules, but a lot of codebase will be able to put all their code into interface with little drawback (like how much parallelisation is possible). I think most new code using modules will put definition in class, given a good implementation of course.

Comment: Hm, we'll see how that evolves... I personally would appreciate if code separation remains just as common with modules as it is now with headers. It is much more convenient to see all the functions I can use at one place without having to skip the definitions first. Admitted, a good IDE might collapse them by default, still I'm feeling a bit uncomfortable with that thought. Sometimes I peek into headers with ordinary text editiors, if I don't have IDE open already – because these open faster...

Comment: If you look at languages like Swift, there's no reason why you couldn't generate a user-readable header from a module file dynamically. The advantage here being that you can omit certain things like protected and private methods, leading to better encapsulation of implementation details, while saving you error-prone copy-pasting to generate prototypes.